# "git push origin master" stop in half way

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

When i use "git push origin master".Git stop when it comes to "Total XXX ,reused 0 < delta 0>".It looks like below image.

I hope some kindful man can help me to fix this question.

[image]

Normally, Git should come to lines like below

[image]

Comment: Finally.I fix it.I turn on my VPN, and the better network makes it go through all the lines.Actually,it never stops, it just goes slowly.

Comment: You really should flag this for deletion.  It was not really an issue with git.

Answer (score 2):

The important thing to note here is that you are pushing 714 objects, which in total amount to 14+ MB in your first screen share.

Given the amount of data to be transferred, it is quite probable that such issues (where the push doesn't work) happen in the future as well on slower connections. To safeguard against these, commit your changes often and push them frequently.